# How to fit a logistic regression for 1 dependent variable and 1 qualitative variable measured twice

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model

I am struggling to fit a simple logistic regression for one dependent value (group) by one independent qualitative variable (dilat) measured twice independently (rater).

I try many solutions and think according http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/ that the solution is a Mixed Effects Logistic Regression.

```r
glmer_dilat<-glmer(group ~ dilat + (1 | rater), data = ex, family = binomial)
summary(glmer_dilat)
```

```r
Generalized linear mixed model fit by the Laplace approximation 
Formula: group ~ dilat + (1 | rater) 
   Data: ex 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance
 105.5 112.5 -49.74    99.48
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 rater  (Intercept)  0        0      
Number of obs: 76, groups: rater, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   0.8473     0.4880   1.736   0.0825 .
dilat        -1.2827     0.5594  -2.293   0.0219 *
```

But the result is the same without !

```r
summary(glm(group ~ dilat, data =ex, family = binomial))

glm(formula = group ~ dilat, family = binomial, data = ex)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.552  -0.999  -0.999   1.367   1.367  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   0.8473     0.4879   1.736   0.0825 .
dilat        -1.2826     0.5594  -2.293   0.0219 *
```

What is the solution?

please find my data set here after applying a dput command to it.

```r
structure(list(id = structure(c(38L, 11L, 6L, 28L, 3L, 30L, 39L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 32L, 29L, 34L, 35L, 33L, 16L, 27L, 5L, 36L, 10L, 9L, 14L, 1L, 13L, 31L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 15L, 24L, 25L, 37L, 26L, 38L, 11L, 6L, 28L, 3L, 30L, 39L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 32L, 29L, 34L, 35L, 33L, 16L, 27L, 5L, 36L, 10L, 9L, 14L, 1L, 13L, 31L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 24L, 37L, 26L), .Label = c("1038835", "2025267", "2053954", "3031612", "40004760", "40014515", "40040532", "40092413", "40101857", "40105328", "4016213", "40187296", "40203950", "40260642", "40269263", "40300349", "40308059", "40327146", "40333651", "40364468", "40435267", "40440293", "40443920", "40485124", "40609779", "40628741", "40662695", "5025220", "E9701737", "M/377313", "qsc22913", "QSC29371", "QSC43884", "QSC62220", "QSC75555", "QSC92652", "QSD01289", "QSD02237", "U/FY0296" ), class = "factor"), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rater = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), dilat = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), midbrain_atroph = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), quadrigemi_atroph = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hum_sig = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), flower_sig = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fp_atroph = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), scp_atroph = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", "group", "rater", "dilat", "midbrain_atroph", "quadrigemi_atroph", "hum_sig", "flower_sig", "fp_atroph", "scp_atroph"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -76L))
```

Comment: Hi CharlesLondon, welcome to the site! Could you provide the model outputs? The regression coefficients are expected to be the same, but what about the standard errors?

Comment: Hi, yes of course:

Comment: Charles: Please don't paste the output in the comments, but edit your question (click on "edit").

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: It is now done.

Comment: There is something strange going on with your data: The outputs are exactly identical because there seem to be no random effects in `rater`. Could you provide a glimpse into your dataset (you don't need to post the full dataset, a partial output is okay).

Comment: How can I paste my list correctly from an excel sheet ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a random effect in rater as the two different raters are two independent radiographers evaluating the presence or not of the sign dilat.

Comment: Use the R function `dput` to get a pasteable version that can be directly put back into R

Comment: dataset provided entirely with the dput R function

Answer (score 1):

This is because `rater` is providing no information about `group` (or to be more precise, `group` does not vary by `rater`). If you look at your data, `group` is exactly the same for each `rater`. So it's not surprising that the variance of the `group` random effect of `group` is 0, and that excluding the random effect gives you the same result.

Comment: I spent a lot of time searching in internet how to do that but I failed. Has anyone any idea how to proceed ?